# How get miscellaneous images src jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Good day, I want to use Lightbox in my site and i want to change img view with lightbox...

```js
$('img').wrap('<a href="#" data-lightbox="lightbox" class="lightbox-link"></a>');
$('.lightbox-link').attr({'href': $('img').attr('src')});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-us">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Lightbox Example</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/css/lightbox.css">
</head>
<body>
<div>
  <img src="http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/images/thumb-3.jpg" alt=""/>
  <img src="http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/images/thumb-4.jpg" alt="" />
  <img src="http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/images/thumb-5.jpg" alt="" />
</div>
  
  <script src="http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/js/lightbox-plus-jquery.min.js"></script>
    
</body>
</html>
```

The problem is when I get img `src` with jQuery his get only first and one `src` and put him for all links attribute `href`... How i can get all `src` and put in the appropriate links?

Comment: loop on all img

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a each loop to loop each img and wrap each image individually with the current image src

```js
$('img').each(function() {
  $(this).wrap('<a href="' + $(this).attr('src') + '" data-lightbox="lightbox" class="lightbox-link"></a>');
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-us">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Lightbox Example</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/css/lightbox.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div>
    <img src="http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/images/thumb-3.jpg" alt="" />
    <img src="http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/images/thumb-4.jpg" alt="" />
    <img src="http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/images/thumb-5.jpg" alt="" />
  </div>

  <script src="http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/js/lightbox-plus-jquery.min.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

use [**Arraymap**](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_map.asp) function.It will get all the src of the image.
And apply with `find()` src of the image.

```js
$('img').wrap('<a href="#" data-lightbox="lightbox" class="lightbox-link"></a>');
$('.lightbox-link').map(function (){
 $(this) .attr({'href': $(this).find('img').attr('src')});
  })
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-us">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Lightbox Example</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/css/lightbox.css">
</head>
<body>
<div>
  <img src="http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/images/thumb-3.jpg" alt=""/>
  <img src="http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/images/thumb-4.jpg" alt="" />
  <img src="http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/images/thumb-5.jpg" alt="" />
</div>
  
  <script src="http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/js/lightbox-plus-jquery.min.js"></script>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, but your answer don't work now.. Why?

Comment: Sorry i forget the click event.see my updated answer

Answer (score 1):

```
$('img').wrap('<a href="#" data-lightbox="lightbox" class="lightbox-link"></a>');
$('.lightbox-link').each(function() {
$(this).attr({'href': $(this).children('img').attr('src')});
});
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/6z6h7mb7/1/

So, you need to loop through created links and get children/images src... P.S> Notice usage of $(this) to point on current element, rather than your selector $('img').

Answer (score 1):

Use `.find` function.

Further more, you need to loop through hyperlinks and get image descendent.

View reference [here](https://api.jquery.com/find/)

```js
$('img').wrap('<a href="#" data-lightbox="lightbox" class="lightbox-link"></a>');
$('.lightbox-link').each(function() {
     $(this).attr({'href': $(this).find('img').attr('src')});
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-us">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Lightbox Example</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/css/lightbox.css">
</head>
<body>
<div>
  <img src="http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/images/thumb-3.jpg" alt=""/>
  <img src="http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/images/thumb-4.jpg" alt="" />
  <img src="http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/images/thumb-5.jpg" alt="" />
</div>
  
  <script src="http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/js/lightbox-plus-jquery.min.js"></script>
    
</body>
</html>
```